# Visualizing categorical data with 7 variables

Tags: r, categorical-data

I'm working with a grouped data set on the presence of a particular disease (Byssinosis):

```
>head(data)

    Employment Smoking Sex Race Workspace Byssinosis Non.Byssinosis
 1        <10     Yes   M    W         1          3             37
 2        <10     Yes   M    O         1         25            139
 3        <10     Yes   F    W         1          0              5
 4        <10     Yes   F    O         1          2             22
 5        <10      No   M    W         1          0             16
 6        <10      No   M    O         1          6             75

>str(data)
'data.frame':    72 obs. of  7 variables:
  $ Employment    : Factor w/ 3 levels "<10",">=20","10-19": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 ...
  $ Smoking       : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
  $ Sex           : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 ...
  $ Race          : Factor w/ 2 levels "O","W": 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
  $ Workspace     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ Byssinosis    : int  3 25 0 2 0 6 0 1 8 8 ...
  $ Non.Byssinosis: int  37 139 5 22 16 75 4 24 21 30 ...
```

And here is a description of my data set:

In 1973, a large cotton textile company in North Carolina participated in a study to investigate the prevalence of byssinosis, a form of pneumoconiosis to which workers exposed to cotton dust are subject. Data was collected on 5,419 workers.

Type of work place [1 (most dusty), 2 (less dusty), 3 (least
dusty)]
Employment, years [< 10, 10–19, 20+]
Smoking [Smoker, or not in last 5 years]
Sex [Male, Female]
Race [White, Other]
Byssinosis [number of cases having the disease]
Non.Byssinosis [number of cases not having the disease]

I plan on running a logistic regression on this data set to see the relationship between my response variable and my predictor variables, but I want to visualize my data before regressing. What would be the best way to do that considering I have multiple variables with some having multiple factors?

Comment: For clarification: what are your individual observations/cases? The fact that you have variables that indicate smokers or gender suggests that an observation is a person but the fact that your Byssinosis variable measures the number of people with the disease suggests you're looking at work places as unit of observation.

Comment: @MaartenPunt This data was collected in 1973 from a large cotton textile company. There were a total of 5,419 workers so if you add up the columns of Byssinosis and Non.Byssinosis you get 5,419.

Comment: @MaartenPunt From my understanding, each row in Byssinosis and Non.Byssinosis is the number of workers with the combination of the variables in that row of the data frame. So for example, in row 1 there were a total of 3 workers who had Byssinosis. Those 3 workers have been employed at the company for <10 years, are smokers, male, White, and worked in the most dusty work place. There were also 37 workers who did not have Byssinosis, and those 37 workers have been employed at the company for <10 years, are smokers, male, White, and worked in the most dusty work place.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be difficult to consider multiple variables at the same time as it gets messy pretty quick.

If you consider one independent variable at a time I would recommend a stacked bar graph that stacks the percentage of people **within a category** that do and do not get the disease with each bar representing a category.

You would then for example see the percentage of smokers that do and do not get the disease (of the total of all smokers) and next to that the same for the non-smokers. By looking at percentages within a category you take away the fact that you may have more people in one category than in another and only look at how often the disease occurs relatively within the different categories.

This visualization easily adapts to multiple categories, you'd just have more bars.

If you really want to consider multiple independents at the same time you may be able to pull that off by "merging" categories looking e.g. at the relative prevalence of the disease in the category smokers that work in a dusty work place vs smokers that do not work in a dusty work place vs non-smokers that do work in a dusty work placevs non-smokers that do not work in a dusty work place, but as I said that gets messy pretty quickly.

EDIT:

As a visual explanation here is a stacked bar graph of the survival rates by gender of the titanic (data from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130813225459/http://www.encyclopedia-titanica.org/titanic_passenger_list/) )

[image]

This clearly shows that they had a policy of women (and children?) first.

The following graph combines gender and passenger/crew type, showing how it becomes messier when you want to show all categories (note that some categories have 0 count e.g. female deck crew, which is why the colums are missing), but the gender effect is still present as is the fact that survival rates are higher for the "upper class" passengers and (perhaps unsurprising)  the deck crew.

[image]